# ADO Connection String

Tags: vbscript, connection-string, ado

```
<%'On Error Resume Next     
Set objConn = Nothing
Dim strConnect 

strConnect = "Provider=sqloledb;Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;1433" 
     "Initial Catalog=mydatabasename;"
     "User Id=userID;Password=password;"

Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open strConnect
```

I'm coding in Dreamweaver for my website. But somehow it doesnt link to the database. 
My database in Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2. I've tried all the strings as stated in http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008. But doesnt seem to link.

Anything wrong im doing here? Sorry about the bad alignment, im still getting used to stackoverflow's alignment methods

Comment: Please add details of the error message

Comment: Hi @AlexK. Whenever i edit it and run the page, it shows 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have multiple servers. One server is on MySQL and this is running on MSSQL. Both servers contain identical information. Just that on different SQL. MySQL connection string works well. Only MSSQL is giving me problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you've posted is your actual connection string, it's malformed. You have a `;` instead of `:` before the port number, and no `;` after it.

```
strConnect = "Provider=sqloledb;Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;1433"
```

This should be

```
strConnect = "Provider=sqloledb;Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx:1433;"
```

When in doubt, write out the connection string and look at what you're actually using in opening the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After changing from `;` to `:`. Its still not connecting to the database. :/

Comment: There was more than one change in that string above. Did you get them both? Also, did you do what I suggested and write out the **entire** connection string and see what it actually was you were using in it's entirety?

Comment: Hi @ken, sorry was away. Yes i did make the two changes.
This is part of a .inc file for my asp website. I tested the connection string using VB2010 and did a connection test. It worked, but when edit in .inc file. I am not able to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

According to both [How To Set the SQL Server Network Library in an ADO Connection String](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238949) and your linked reference, that should be Network Library, not Library:

```
strConnect = "Provider=sqloledb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;;Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;1433" 
 "Initial Catalog=mydatabasename;"
 "User Id=userID;Password=password;"
```

Comment: Hi @remou, sorry was away. I tried as u suggest. Still no luck. Hi 
This is part of a .inc file for my asp website. I tested the connection string using VB2010 and did a connection test. It worked, but when edit in .inc file. I am not able to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

should be

Provider=sqloledb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx,1433

note the comma for the explicit port and the Network word.

Though it may be best to just use Data Source=xxxx;

and set up network library specifics via the xxxx alias in cliconfg

Comment: also 1433 is default port anyway

Comment: Finally ensure TCP/IP is enabled for SQL server as it is not by default.